# How to modify and presist member / embedded array in "dynamic" object (the one declared with dynamic keyword)

Tags: c#, arrays, json, generics, dynamic

I have:

```
dynamic dObj = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(contentsOfJsonFile) // returns dynamic..
```

where:

```
dObj.title // is a flat sting
dObj.description // is a flat sting
dObj.tags // is an array! ["videos", "pictures", "other assets"]
```

Now in dynamic variable, how to modify the embedded array?

When I access dObj.tags[0] it returns string value. But when I do:

```
Json.Encode(dObj) // array unplugged, object empty
```

It loses the empties the embedded array. Even if I don't modify anything, it still loses the embedded array. I tried to cast it to generics:

```
List<string> list = (List<string>)dObj.tags;
```

But it throws an exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'`

Question:

How to modify member array of dynamic object, such that it persist the changes when `Json.Encode(dObj)` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute this adjustment after decoding:

```
dObj.tags = new List<dynamic>( dObj.tags );
```

Despite of this hiccup, the serialization and deserialization of dynamic object with `System.Web.Helpers.Json` is bit faster than `JSON.NET`.